# Why isn't United States an option on the UK "check if you need a visa" site?

Tags: visas, uk

While I'm sure I can find an answer to this elsewhere, I'm still just confused by this. Why would [the primary government site for checking if you need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y) not list the US?

Every other country seems to be there!

Comment: It has "USA" on the list? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @neo, nice one. Quickly spotted and voted upon. v nice

Comment: Lol yep didn't see that. Blind spot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The dropdown list contains "USA" which is a common way to list the United States, in the same fashion as "UK" is often used for United Kingdom.

[image]

As to why is appears first in the "U" section, it is an abbreviation not a name and abbreviations are often listed before full names.

Comment: Hilarious answer. Thanks. I can just picture you stabbing a finger at the screen emphatically.

Comment: More than a principled decision to list abbreviations first, the form is probably just listing its options in Unicode codepoint order, in which upper-case letters come before lower-case. Note also that São Tomé is sorted _after_ Syria.

Comment: That's the normal sort order for a computer, and has been since, oh, the 1960s or even earlier. It takes work to override that, and programmers are lazy.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - As the web form is html, the drop down is most likely a cut & paste code snippet, borrowed from some other source, since as you said programmers are lazy. So no telling how it was originally generated.